# Need some clarification regarding error handling in kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm looking over the following site [KIP:298: Error Handling in Connect](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-298%3A+Error+Handling+in+Connect)

In example 2, what does the following configuration will do? Bit more information or an example can help me out to understand.:-

```
# retry for at most 10 minutes times waiting up to 30 seconds between consecutive failures
errors.retry.timeout=600000
errors.retry.delay.max.ms=30000
```

And one more thing is, while dealing with sink connector, when I'm getting some errors due to duplicate records, it keeps on trying for a certain period, **how to set our own limit of retries?**
I tried by setting `errors.retry.timeout=0` even though duplicate key error was retrying continuously for certain no.of.times, but if the error is because of schema or serializer it's not retrying.

And finally, `errors.log.enable` when this is true where does these logs are stored? I was checking in connect log, but not able to find the difference between default log and when the errors.log.enable is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to fix your problem ,but when `errors.log.enable=true`, you should see 2 additional topic are created for your connector, `yourconnector-error` and `yourconnector-success`, you should be able to see the connector failure message in `yourconnector-error` topic.